# Cannot read property LENGTH of undefined / jquery dropDown plugin

Tags: jquery, html

Could anyone help as to why this is not working for me?

I followed the instructions as per the documentation, here:
 [Custom Dropdown Image ComboBox](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/550/jQuery-custom-dropdown-image-combobox) but it keeps throwing me the
"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" alert.

I have downloaded the plugin, and installed it in the relevant place, 
my header looks like this:

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=css/stylepage.css>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=css/dd.css>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.dd.js"></script>
```

Here is the HTML select:

```
 <select id="exchange" name="exchange">
        <option value="points" title="images/coins.png"> Credits </option>
        <option value="money" title="images/money_dollar.png">Money </option>
        <option value="stocks" title="images/stock.png">Stocks</option>
 </select>
```

jquery (in body):

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
try {
$("body select").msDropDown();
} catch(e) {
alert(e.message);
}
});
</script>

</body>
```

Can anyone advise why?

There are no other SELECT elements on the page and no other ID's with the id of #exchange.

I have tried replacing $("body select") with $("#exchange") in the document ready function too.

Please help

Comment: I don't see the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/EmQWQ/

Comment: hmm, i copied the whole fiddle page source to a blank page o nmy server, and it works perfectly.

So, where do you think the problem lies? within my script files?

Comment: I guess tha's the consequence of not including AL of my code for analysis.

right, I had another option "property" which I never had an image for yet. I excluded this option when I opsted this question.

Turns out, if one of my options does NOT have a title, that is why I was getting the undefined error.

oops! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

if you have options that all have titles (img links)

```
<select id="exchange" name="exchange">
        <option value="points" title="images/coins.png"> Credits </option>
        <option value="money" title="images/money_dollar.png">Money </option>
        <option value="stocks" title="images/stock.png">Stocks</option>
 </select>
```

IT WILL WORK!

-

if you have any blank options (like below)

```
<select id="exchange" name="exchange">
        <option value="points" title="images/coins.png"> Credits </option>
        <option value="money" title="images/money_dollar.png">Money </option>
        <option value="stocks" title="images/stock.png">Stocks</option>
        <option value="blank">blank</option>

 </select>
```

IT WILL NOT WORK and give the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" alert.